# Payment sheet is showing on IOS but not on Android Flutter Stripe

Tags: android, ios, flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-stripe

Payment sheet is working fine on IOS devices but not on Android devices. I have completed the android integration steps as describe in the ReadMe file. Code is working fine.. i am able to initialize payment sheet. But i am not able to present payment sheet. Its also not showing any kind of exception
Following is the code:

```
  Future<void> addPaymentMethod() async {
    String? customerId = locator<PaymentConfig>().getCustomerCred!.customerId;
    if (customerId != null) {
      Result<String, String?> result = await PayIn.createSetupIntent(customerId: customerId);
      result.when((errorCode) {
        PaymentExceptions.handleException(errorCode: errorCode);
      }, (secretKey) async {
        if (secretKey != null) {
        try {
          await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
              paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
                  setupIntentClientSecret: secretKey,
                  customerId: customerId,
                  style: ThemeMode.dark));
          await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet();
          await getUserPaymentMethods();
          setBusy(true);
          await getUserPaymentMethods(save: true);
        } on Exception catch (_) {
          Loader.hideLoader();
        }
      }
      });
    }
  }
```

In the above code, when i am calling present payment sheet, it's not showing payment sheet nor its giving any error. After **await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet()** no code is executing...
**Additional Info:**
Here in this code i am adding payment method using Setup Intent

Comment: Could you please provide more details about your integration ? Are there any particular log messages at runtime ? Did you try to run the PaymentSheet from the official flutter example ? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/tree/master/example

Comment: No log error message gets shown in the console after  **Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet()** code line..also i am only following this https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/blob/main/README.md#requirements ... i have not yet followed the example suggested by you...is there any difference? @os4m37

Comment: @os4m37... i was able to solve the error...the problem wasn't the android integration ...i was not passing the 'merchantDisplayName' when initializing the payment sheet...it was working fine on IOS without the 'merchantDisplayName'...but i think its compulsory when it comes to Android devices

Comment: Glad to hear that you managed to fix the issue, Thanks for sharing the information!